# how to convert join in my sql query to laravel ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I'm new in laravel 5 how can i convert this query to laravel ORM

```
 select `users`.`id`, `users`.`username`, count(`ord`.`id`) As total 
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `orders` AS `ord`  ON `ord`.`empolyee_id` = `users`.`id`
AND  DATE(`ord`.`created_at`) = $date
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work correctly

```
 $orders = Order::rightjoin('users',function($join)  use($date){
        $join->on('users.id', '=','orders.empolyee_id');
        $join->on("DATE(created_at)", '=', $date);
    })
        ->select(DB::raw('count(orders.id) as total, users.username'))
        ->groupBy('users.id')->get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you select only `username` and `total`, you probably want an array instead of eloquent results, that's why `lists` at the end. If you still want the collection of models, then use `get` instead.

```
$users = User::leftJoin('orders as o', function($join) use ($date) {
      $join->on('users.id', '=', 'o.empolyee_id')
           ->where(DB::raw('DATE(o.created_at)'), '=', $date);
   })
   ->selectRaw('count(o.id) as total, users.username')
   ->groupBy('users.id')
   ->lists('total', 'username')
```